# Why my Highcharts.chart xAxis doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I want to create chart, I found that there is something weird.
[image]
[image]
[image]
The value sequence is correct, but xAxis categories aren't as my expectation.
I want to know how to fix this problem.
If need another information, please let me know.

Comment: You need to provide the code so we can see what the problem is. We can't debug an image

Comment: Also the version of Highcharts you're using.  It may be a bug in that version

Comment: I don't know highcharts which version is because I use script(src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js").

Comment: So I think it should be the newest version?

Comment: My image is about how I set the parameter to genarate the chart.

Comment: I certify that my data is correct because I checked out its value in Chrome debug mode.

Comment: I find my version is 10.3.1

Comment: As I said, you need to provide code that duplicates the problem, rather than screenshots of the code. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for further details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the category type axis, the first column is placed on the x=0 at the xAxis, which corresponds to the first value of the categories array. If you set the first `series.data` x to 1, it takes the second value from the categories array. You can easily fix that, by setting null as the first value:

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: [null, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aemvthz6/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories